# merging two daily time series with overlapping dates

Tags: r, datetime, merge

I have two daily time series  with 20 stations listed as  id  and I am trying to  merge these two dataframe in R.
The dataframes columns headings are as follows.

```
names(data1)
"id"     "year"   "yday"   "date"   "t_1"  "t_2"  "t_3" "r1"   "s1"   "p1" "s2"
names(data2)
"id"     "year"   "yday"   "date"   "t_1"  "t_2"  "t_3" "r1"   "s1"   "p1"
```

I tried to merge it using the following code

```
newdata<- merge(data1,data2, all=TRUE)
```

This is only partial solution. However, for certain id, the dates between the two dataframe overlap and also for same date there are NAs in data1, while data2 do not have missing values. I am trying to merge it so that I can get rid of the duplicate dates for each id, while at the same time retain the data which is available for duplication and retain the columns headings for data1. Eg this is how it merge

```
id     year     yday    date     t_1    t_2  t_3     r1 s1  p1  s2

AA1111  2007    3   03/01/2007  -5.3    -11.6   -8.5    0   0   0   NA          
AA1111  2007    3   03/01/2007  -5.3    -11.6   NA  NA  NA  0   32
```

I would like

```
id     year     yday    date     t_1    t_2     t_3   r1    s1  p1  s2

AA1111  2007    3   03/01/2007  -5.3    -11.6   -8.5    0   0   0   32
```

The codes above above didn't give me quite my desired results. Your guidance on how i can get my desired result would be very appreciated ( as i am still trying with R)

Comment: There are two "s1"s in names(data1). Is this something you really have?

Comment: sorry i corrected it

Comment: Thanks for that. Would it be possible for you to upload a reproducible data? The current information is not good enough for SO users to look into your case. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a representative data, here's an approach based on a sample data I created.

```
# sample merged data (hope it represents your data fully)
DF = structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AA1111", 
"AA1112"), class = "factor"), year = c(2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L), yday = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "03/01/2007", class = "factor"), t_1 = c(-5.3, 
-5.3, -10.3, -10.3, NA), t_2 = c(-11.6, -11.6, -11.6, NA, -11.6
), t_3 = c(-8.5, NA, -8.5, -8.5, -8.5), r1 = c(0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 
0L), s1 = c(0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L), p1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L), 
    s2 = c(NA, 32L, NA, 42L, NA)), .Names = c("id", "year", "yday", 
"date", "t_1", "t_2", "t_3", "r1", "s1", "p1", "s2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

#       id year yday       date   t_1   t_2  t_3 r1 s1 p1 s2
# 1 AA1111 2007    3 03/01/2007  -5.3 -11.6 -8.5  0  0  0 NA
# 2 AA1111 2007    3 03/01/2007  -5.3 -11.6   NA NA NA  0 32
# 3 AA1112 2008    3 03/01/2007 -10.3 -11.6 -8.5  0  0  0 NA
# 4 AA1112 2008    3 03/01/2007 -10.3    NA -8.5  0  0 NA 42
# 5 AA1112 2008    3 03/01/2007    NA -11.6 -8.5  0  0  0 NA

library(data.table)
setDT(DF) # convert to data table
DF_new <- DF[, names(DF)[5:11] := lapply(.SD, max, na.rm=TRUE),
             by=list(id,year,yday,date), .SDcols=5:11][,unique(.SD)]
DF_new
#        id year yday       date   t_1   t_2  t_3 r1 s1 p1 s2
# 1: AA1111 2007    3 03/01/2007  -5.3 -11.6 -8.5  0  0  0 32
# 2: AA1112 2008    3 03/01/2007 -10.3 -11.6 -8.5  0  0  0 42

setDF(DF_new) # convert back to data frame
```

`.SD` stands for *Subset of Data* and contains the data for each group specified in `by`. It itself is a data.table. `.SDcols` argument tells which columns should `.SD` contain. The syntax `LHS := RHS` runs the expression in the RHS - here, loop over .SD which contains columns specified in `.SDcols` and compute `max`, and updates the columns specified in LHS *by reference* (in-place).

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! Would it be possible for you to explain the second line your codes! Thank you.

Comment: @nee, Was away. Glad it helps. Unsure which 2nd line. Anyhow, do you understand the additional comments added by Arun (the co-developer of data.table package)? Guess it may have explained what you're asking.